# How can I train API using Watson AlchemyAPI?

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I am trying to find out the entity from text input. If there any option to train Alchemy. So that I can modify entity according to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** train the entity extraction from AlchemyLanguage but there are other Watson APIs that you can use to extract entities or concepts from text.

- [Relationship Extraction](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/relationship-extraction.html): Performs linguistic analysis of the input text. It then finds spans of text and clusters them together to form entities, before finally extracting the relationships between them.

  [image: Relationship extraction]
- [Concept Insights](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/concept-insights.html): Helps you annotate concepts and identify conceptual associations from text. 
  [image: Concept Insights]

  You can quickly test this API Swagger: https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/concept-insights-v2